# initialization Materialize-autocomplete dataset using api call with ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, materialize

Good morning all,
I am using materialize.css in a PHP app

I will want to initialize the auto-complete data with an API call.

The `.autocomplete ()` initializes the data with a JSON array `" data ":`,

which I get with the `.ajax ({..., url: '/search.php', ... datas})`.

but I can't inject the `datas` into the`.autocomplete ()`,

how can I do it?

Here is the source code:

```
<body>
  <form action="">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">title</i>
            <input id="searchOnAPI" name="name" type="text" class="autocomplete" value="{{ item.name }} ">
            <label for="searchOnAPI">{{ siteData('admin.titre') }}</label>
            <ul id="autocomplete-content" class="autocomplete-content"><li><a></a></li></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#searchOnAPI').keyup(function () {
        $('#autocomplete-content').html('');
        let search = $(this).val();

        if (search !== "") {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/search.php',
            data: 'search=' + encodeURIComponent(search),
            success: function (datas) {
            if (datas !== "") {
              $('#searchOnAPI').autocomplete(datas);
            } else {
            document.getElementById('autocomplete-content').innerHTML = '<ul class="autocomplete-content dropdown-content"><li><a class="black-text">{{ siteData('site.search.nodata') }}</a></li></ul>';
            }
          }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I think the problem comes from here:

The variable datas ...

but I don't understand the error anymore.

```js
success: function (datas) {
   if (datas !== "") {
      $('#searchOnAPI').autocomplete(datas);
   }
```

the code of the search page:
and call API

```php
<?php

if (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = trim(htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']));

    $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_URL             => "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/multi?api_key=". API_KEY ."&language=fr-FR&query=$search",
            CURLOPT_CAINFO          => dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."cert.tmdb.cer", //api.themoviedb.org
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 10,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => "GET"
        ]);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);


        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        $err = json_decode($err, true);
        $datas = [];

        if (!is_null($err) || $response === null || !isset($response['results'])) {
            $datas[] = ['No Data' => null];
        } else {

            $response = $response['results'];
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
                if (isset($response[$i]['title'])) {
                    $datas[] = $response[$i]['title'] ;
                } elseif (isset($response[$i]['name'])) {
                    $datas[] = $response[$i]['name'];
                }
            }
            
            echo json_encode(array_fill_keys(['data'], array_fill_keys($datas, null)), true);
        }

}
```

and here is the api return in json of the search page

```
{
  "data": {
    "O Amor Acontece": null,
    "Quem Quer Namorar Com o Agricultor?": null,
    "O'": null,
    "O Clone": null,
    "Hawaï police d'État": null,
    "O Matador": null
  }
}
```

Any advice is welcome!
.EDD

Comment: Looks like the API call is happening on keyup? Is that the place you want to initialize? Or I am missing something?

Comment: Yes for the moment it is the case but in the future I will modify it from sort to make a call every X seconds ...

But my problem is that I can't inject the JSON return from the search.php page into my autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/search.php',
    data: 'search=' + encodeURIComponent(search),
    success: function (datas) {
```

I did not set the dataType ...

`dataType:"json",`

like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:"json",
    url: '/search.php',
    data: 'search=' + encodeURIComponent(search),
    success: function (datas) {
```

But with everything works.

find on [Jquery autocomplete _renderItem is not working][1]

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP code is returning a json object with a 'data' parameter, maybe you could try

```
   if (datas !== "") {
      $('#searchOnAPI').autocomplete(datas.data);
   }
```